# Issues with using WTelegram on a MAUI application for android

Tags: c#, android, maui, wtelegramclient

Everything works fine if I run my .NET MAUI app on Windows machine. But if I deploy on Android VM, below code to initialize WTelegram client is giving error as

> Access to the path '/data/user/0/WTelegram.session' is denied.'

```
_client = new WTelegram.Client(int.Parse(API_ID), API_HASH);
```

I understand that, this is due to the permission issue in creating session file. I changed the code to below as per some suggestions on forums

```
string SessionPath = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath + "/WTelegram.session";
_client = new WTelegram.Client(int.Parse(API_ID), API_HASH, SessionPath);
```

But it gives error as

> 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'

Does WTelgram client not support Android?
**Is there an alternate I can use in my MAUI project targeting Android?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this subject, I would recommend you go to our Github issues page and check for existing issues (like [this one](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/issues/100) or [that one](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/issues/62)) or open a new issue.

> 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'

You'll need to give us more detail if you want to help us identify the cause
(callstack with filename & line details)

I know WTelegramClient works under Xamarin/Android, but I personally never tested it under MAUI.

Judging by the Github issues I linked above, other people did and had to redirect the default Console logging to elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. Turning off the logging as suggested in the forum solved the issue